# real valued function

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $f:\Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{R}$ be a function. If $f(n)=f(n+11)=f(n+18)$ for all $n$ belong to $\Bbb{Z}$ ,then show that $f$ is a constant function.
I think that $f$ has two period which not multiple of each other so it must be constant function.
But I can't find any rigorous proof. Plz help me to find out the proof. Thanks

Comment: Hint: $\;5 \cdot 11 - 3 \cdot 18 = 1\,$.

Comment: This is not functional analysis. Please use a more suitable tag.

Comment: I will take care next time

Answer (score 2):

$f(n) = f(n+11) = f(n+22) = f(n+33) = f(n+44) = f(n+55)$ for all $n$.

$f(n+1) = f(n+19) = f(n+37) = f(n+55)$ for all $n$.

Hence, $f(n) = f(n+1)$ for all $n$. With induction, this shows that $f(n) = f(1)$ for all $n$,which is a constant.

Comment: f(z)=f(z+1)=f(z+i) for all z belong to Complex number .Is f is constant.

Comment: I don't immediately know. Ask your question to everybody, not only to me. Then you might get an answer.